# How can I create a script that examines a list of numbers to determine the second largest number?

Tags: python-2.7

```
list1=[2,8,64,16,32,4]
import heapq
heapq.nlargest(2, list1)
```

This is the progress I have made so far. I am (extremely) new to python as you can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heapq.nlargest returns a list. SO you need the last element of this list.

heapq.nlargest(2, list1)[-1] --> Gives you the answer.

Comment: in case of undesired repetitions you can use make a set of list1 first